# Tumblr integration in android

Tags: android

In my app I want to integrate tumblr and getting photos from tumblr. On Github I have found "TumblrExample". In this sample I have replaced my consumer key and consumer secret and when I run this app I am getting following exception:

> dalvikvm :Could not find class 'oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer', referenced from method com.robertszkutak.androidexamples.tumblrexample.TumblrExampleActivity.<clinit>
>
> java.lang.VerifyError: com/robertszkutak/androidexamples/tumblrexample/TumblrExampleActivity

I have studied full documentation of tumblr api. In that api all webservices available to get the data. To get the photos from tumblr api the following websevice is useed:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{hostname}/posts?api_key={consumer key}&type=photo
```

How can I authorise and get the hostname programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also getting same problem in same sample i.e "TumblrExample". But, I replace signpost-commonshttp4.jar, signpost-core.jar with latest and also i change version i.e 1.6 to 2.3 its works perfect.

Use signpost-commonshttp4.jar and signpost-core.jar from here:
https://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/list

Comment: Answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463342/tumblr-integration-in-android-app